# Can't Interact with Iframe on Community Cloud LWC

Tags: iframe, community-cloud

So I have added a SoundCloud player to my Community Cloud using an iframe on a LWC but I can't interact with the player(i.e. can't click on pause or play, can't click on share,etc.). I know for a fact the player works and it's connected because if I set the player to autoplay it starts playing the podcast its supposed to(but I can't pause it since I can't directly interact with it).

Here is the code:

```
<template>
        <iframe class="soundCloudPlayer" width="94%" height="156" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" allow="autoplay" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/649063052&color=%23ff5500&auto_play=true&hide_related=false&show_comments=false&show_user=false&show_reposts=false&show_teaser=true"></iframe></template>
```

Any ideas? Is there some kind of interaction between SF Communities and iframes that disables this? Thank you for your help.

Comment: MIght be clickjacking protection of SF? can you try disabling from setup?
https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/secdev_application_logic_vulnerabilities/secdev_app_logic_clickjacking

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I actually found out that while in app builder mode you can't run scripts on an iframe. Once I published the site it worked without issues.